# How to match this string using regex in emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I've try to replace this `<?= T_('XXX'); ?>` for this `{{ T_('XXX') }}`, I've try this

`<\\?= \\([^\\?]+\\) *\\?>` -> `{{ $1 }}`

and can't make it work. What regex and replacement should I use.

PS: is there online Regex tool for Emacs, there is lot of tools out there but I can't find one for emacs (maybe there is tool in emacs itself).

Comment: `M-x` `isearch-forward-regexp`

Comment: quick help: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Regexp

Comment: @abo-abo it's great, excactly what I was looking for to test and learn Regex in Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the replacement, point has to be at buffer start:

```lisp
(replace-regexp "<\\?=\\([^;]+\\); \\?>"
                "{{\\1 }}")
```

Interactively it's <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp`, but each two backslashes from above
you have to replace with just one.

Comment: That was my bad, I've used double backslashes while using `M-x`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you don't need a regexp, a simple string replace will do it:

```
M-x query-replace RET
<?=
RET
{{
```

and then

```
M-x query-replace RET
; ?>
RET
 }}
```

Comment: It's not good because `?>` can start with `<? if` and `<? if` should have `{%` so it need `%}` (It's twig, same as django I think)